# IIS 7 URL Rewriting

Tags: codeigniter, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have been working this one for a few hours now trying get this to work. I have a CodeIgniter website that use to be on an Apache server running fine. I was using the Apache URL Rewriter for the URL in order to hide the index.php. For some reason I cannot get this to work on IIS. I have Googled it and came up with several different options but some either didn't work or redirected me to my root directory.

I am trying to rewrite the URL like so
`http://domain.com/v2.3.1/index.php/test`

Below is my rule from the `web.config` file:

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
             <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

The current configuration will send me back to my root directory. My website is located at an example URL below:

`http://domain/v2.3.1` - This will bring me to my main page

however

`http://domain/v2.3.1/test` - Will take me back to `http://domain` but the URL never changes from `http://domain/v2.3.1/test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing changed on the rule. I had the rule in the wrong directory. The website root was not the domain root, it was in a sub directory. With IIS you need to have the `web.config`in the same directory that you are wanting to rewrite the URL.

After several hours of banging my head I finally figured it out.