# Codeigniter ajax call 404 error on hosting

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, hosting, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to test a codeigniter proyect on hosting; the index page it's rendering without problems, but I have a contact form that sends data via an ajax request, here:

```
$('#send_mail').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  url: baseurl+'email/send',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize()
})
.done(function() {
  console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
  console.log("complete");
});
```

});

When I submit the contact form I'm getting this error:

```
 POST http://novaderma.cl/site/email/send 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4
```

I've been searching on the web and other people have similar problems with the `.htacces` file and `base_url` parameter, so I'm gonna post them too, here:

Config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://novaderma.cl/site/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /site/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>
```

I don't know how to solve this, so please help me !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS 7 URL Rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290837/iis-7-url-rewriting)

Comment: Your server works on IIS on Windows so .htaccess won't help because it's for Apache server. See the URL above for solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi  @Vaviloff! , please would you help me to get solution for this problem ? I can't understand it .

Comment: @Vaviloff Great man !!!!!!! that's it !! thank you !! but I have another problem, I'm thinking it's related to this....I'm trying to send an email by codeigniter and throws me a similar error..."Can't send email using smtp php, maybe your server is not properly configured to use this send method"...any idea ? =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site server works on IIS on Windows so .htaccess won't help because it's for an Apache server.

You need to create `web.config` file in `site` folder, then fill it with the folllowing rule:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
             <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/site/index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Great man !!!!!!! that's it !! thank you !! but I have another problem, I'm thinking it's related to this....I'm trying to send an email by codeigniter and throws me a similar error..."Can't send email using smtp php, maybe your server is not properly configured to use this send method"...any idea ? =(

Comment: Great, was glad to help. As for smtp problems - please open another question, as it's a whole other issue.

Comment: Ok , and how could I add you to that question ? ...for you can help me ?

Answer (score -1):

`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

`

check this code